# how to give a widget, a specific width according to its parent - Flutter

Tags: flutter

there is a scenario that i have a circle and inside that circle i want to show some text. Both items are in a scrollable listview. i want to calculate the width of the parent and then give with to the inner children to be placed and shouldn't move backward or forward from its outer parent circle widget.
i have used stack widget to do so which works fine on a single device or screen but what about other screen sizes?

any suggestion according to this?

Comment: Can you include minimal-snippet that will reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0):

I asked yesterday the same concept question:
the `FractionallySizedBox` is super useful on those cases, it gives the width / height of a children based on the width / height of the parent:

```dart
class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ParentCircle(
          
          height: 250,
          width: 250,
          color: Colors.red,
          child: FractionallySizedBox(
            widthFactor: .5,
            heightFactor: .5, 
            alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
            child: ChildCircle(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this will give the `ChildCircle` a 50% width and 50% height of the `ParentCircle`